# Managing Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, multi-tenant, entity-framework-migrations

I'm developing a multi-tenant web app using Entity Framework, the project is under active development and this process will probably take one year or two. I use `Migrations` to manage database changes, adding new tables and sub-systems, managing database `triggers`, seeding default data and etc. They also will be used when adding new tenant, each customer might have several different databases, and the app is able to build each database using `migrations`.

There is one problem though, it's getting harder and harder to manage changes and keep migrations clean. While we've build less than 10% of the system, I ended up with more than 50 migrations and it took several hours to flat them into three or four logical migrations.

There's yet another issue with this approach: breaking changes. For example, when I use a `view`, adding a field to the main table, doesn’t update the view and blah blah.

Do you know any method to solve these problems? What way do you use to make your app able to build its databases while you're still developing it and it'll change often.

Comment: When it comes to managing migrations, I often refer to this blog post. I get your concept of logical migrations - we essentially do the same by rolling multiple migrations up. http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you have one or a millino migrations. When you apply migrations you can set the target migration, and all the migration operations are executed as a single one.

You can check the `Update-Database` documentation by running `get-help update-database` in the package manager console. These are the possible parameters:

> Update-Database [-SourceMigration ] [-TargetMigration ] [-Script] [-Force] [-ProjectName ] [-StartUpProjectName ] 
>       [-ConfigurationTypeName ] [-ConnectionStringName ] [-AppDomainBaseDirectory ] []
>
> Update-Database [-SourceMigration ] [-TargetMigration ] [-Script] [-Force] [-ProjectName ] [-StartUpProjectName ] 
>       [-ConfigurationTypeName ] -ConnectionString  -ConnectionProviderName  [-AppDomainBaseDirectory ] []

If you specify the target migration, and `-Script` you'll see that all the included migrations create a single SQL script to update the database. If you don't specify that option, the script will be sent to the database server (in the project's connection string).

If you don't specify the target migration, it will migrate the database to the latest migration.

This answers the first part of your question. You don't have to worry about having one, a hundred or a zillion migrations. And there is nothing such as a "Logical Migration".

Regarding the second part of your question, there isn't also any problem. If you need to make a modification in your application, like adding a column to a table, you're supposed to make the change solution wide, i.e. modify the database (by using a migration) and update the solution code to support the new column, i.e. update the business logic, the entities, the view, and whichever related element is in your solution. At this point you have an stable version. If you deploy this version, and update the database to the latest migration, it will work, without "breaking changes". So, whenever you have an stable version in your code, you have to give it a version number, so that you can deploy that version numner. Each version will have compatible code and migrations. You should use a version control system or any other method to keep your stable versions.

Naturally, if you modify your database, and have incompatible code (for example, you remove a column from a table, and your code refers to that column), if you try to deploy it, it will not work. So, you only have to be careful with creating stable versions, and tagging them with the version number only when they're in that state.

I have an application which has the "update to latest migration" db initializer, and, whenever I deploy an upgrade (and even a downgrade) to the application, it works perfectly. The only requisite is that the deployed version is an stable one.